# Invoking HTML page inside war file from explorer

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

I am new to Servlets. I have created a basic HTML `createStudent.html`. The HTML page invokes a servlet in the form action. I am using Eclipse & Tomcat 6.0.  I have deployed the web project on the tomcat server. When I am trying to invoke the HTML page it is not opening.

The project name is `com.student` and the HTML page name is `createStudent.html` which is placed @ location `WebContent\WEB-INF\`.

I am trying to invoke the HTML page with URL `http://localhost:8080/com.student/createStudent.html`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything under WEB-INF is not viewable to the outside world. Move it down one directory to WebContent

Answer (score 1):

Place createStudent.html in WebContent.

```
  com.student\WebContent\createStudent.html
```